# How to compare two arrays by multiple columns (row with row)

Tags: excel, vba

I have two tables in one spreadsheet. both have the same columns - Name, City, Province. My goal is to compare both and if three out of three values in a row match, then pull "Yes", if not, pull "No". I compare rows with rows in these two tables (not random cells).

I have not found a proper formula, so probably need to code it.

I have found a good code, but it works only for looking at the same values in one array. I hope it could be adapted to my problem. Or maybe I need another one.

```
Sub Compare()
    Dim row As Integer
    row = 2
    Dim firstColumn As String
    firstColumn = "H"
    Dim lastColumn As String
    lastColumn = "J"
    Dim resultsColumn As String
    resultsColumn = "M"
    Dim isFoundText As String
    isFoundText = "YES"
    Dim isNotFoundText As String
    isNotFoundText = "NO"

    Do While Range("B" & row).Value <> ""

        Dim startChar As Integer
        startChar = Asc(firstColumn)
        Dim endChar As Integer
        endChar = Asc(lastColumn)
        Dim i As Integer
        Dim hasMatch As Boolean
        hasMatch = False

        For i = startChar To endChar
            If Range(Chr(i) & row).Value = Range(Chr(i + 1) & row).Value Then
                hasMatch = True
            End If
            If Range(Chr(startChar) & row).Value = Range(Chr(i + 1) & row).Value Then
                hasMatch = True
            End If
        Next i

        If (hasMatch) Then
            Range(resultsColumn & row).Value = isFoundText
        Else
            Range(resultsColumn & row).Value = isNotFoundText
        End If
        row = row + 1
    Loop

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this type of task it's better to move that data to *Variant Arrays* and do the looping over those (*much* faster). Also, the the pattern matching can be generalised away from the data, making for a more reusable solution and seperation of concerns

The Compare Function

```
Private Function CompareColumns(Table1 As Range, Table2 As Range, ColPairs() As Variant, Optional IsMatch As Variant = True, Optional NoMatch As Variant = False) As Variant
    Dim Table1Data As Variant
    Dim Table2Data As Variant
    Dim OutputData As Variant
    Dim rw1 As Long, rw2 As Long
    Dim Col As Long
    Dim FoundMatch As Boolean

    ' Move data to variant arrays
    Table1Data = Table1.Value2
    Table2Data = Table2.Value2

    ' Size return array
    ReDim OutputData(1 To UBound(Table1Data, 1), 1 To 1)

    ' Loop the arrays
    For rw2 = 1 To UBound(Table2Data, 1)
        OutputData(rw2, 1) = NoMatch ' initialise
        For rw1 = 1 To UBound(Table1Data, 1)
            FoundMatch = True
            For Col = LBound(ColPairs, 1) To UBound(ColPairs)
                If Table1Data(rw1, ColPairs(Col, 1)) <> Table2Data(rw2, ColPairs(Col, 2)) Then
                    FoundMatch = False ' column not a match, move to next row
                    Exit For
                End If
            Next
            If FoundMatch Then ' found a match
                OutputData(rw2, 1) = IsMatch
                Exit For ' exit Table2 loop when match found
            End If
        Next
    Next
    ' Return result to caller
    CompareColumns = OutputData
End Function
```

Use it like this

```
Sub Compare()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim Table1 As Range
    Dim Table2 As Range
    Dim Output As Range
    Dim OutputTable As Variant
    Dim ColPairs() As Variant

    Set ws = ActiveSheet ' update to suit your needs

    ' Set up ranges by any means you choose
    With ws
        Set Table1 = .Range(.Cells(2, 1), .Cells(.Rows.Count, 3).End(xlUp))
        Set Table2 = .Range(.Cells(2, 10), .Cells(.Rows.Count, 8).End(xlUp))
        Set Output = .Cells(2, 13).Resize(Table2.Rows.Count, 1)
    End With

    'Specify columns to compare
    ReDim ColPairs(1 To 3, 1 To 2)
    ColPairs(1, 1) = 1: ColPairs(1, 2) = 3
    ColPairs(2, 1) = 2: ColPairs(2, 2) = 2
    ColPairs(3, 1) = 3: ColPairs(3, 2) = 1

    ' Call Match function
    OutputTable = CompareColumns(Table1, Table2, ColPairs, "Yes", "No")

    ' Place Output on sheet
    Output = OutputTable
End Sub
```

Answer (score -1):

Adding some indents so we can read this:

```
Sub Compare()
    Dim firstColumn As String, lastColumn As String, resultsColumn As String, isFoundText As String, isNotFoundText As String, 
    Dim row As Integer, startChar As Integer, endChar As Integer, i As Integer
    Dim hasMatch As Boolean
    row = 2
    firstColumn = "H"
    lastColumn = "J"
    resultsColumn = "M"
    isFoundText = "YES"
    isNotFoundText = "NO"
    Do While Range("B" & row).Value <> ""
        startChar = Asc(firstColumn)
        endChar = Asc(lastColumn)
        hasMatch = False
        For i = startChar To endChar
            If Range(Chr(i) & row).Value = Range(Chr(i + 1) & row).Value Then
                hasMatch = True
            End If
            If Range(Chr(startChar) & row).Value = Range(Chr(i + 1) & row).Value Then
                hasMatch = True
            End If
        Next i
        If (hasMatch) Then
            Range(resultsColumn & row).Value = isFoundText
        Else
            Range(resultsColumn & row).Value = isNotFoundText
        End If
        row = row + 1
    Loop
End Sub
```

---

Now, to start making changes... Looks like you can clean up your code with a simpler loop, such that (untested):

```
Dim lri as long, lrj as long, i as long, j as long
lri = cells(rows.count,"H").end(xlup).row
lrj = range(columns("B"),columns("D")).Find("*", , , , xlByRows, xlPrevious).Row
For i = 2 to lri
    For j = 2 to lrj
        If Cells(j,"B").Value = cells(i,"J").Value AND Cells(j,"C").Value = Cells(i,"I").Value AND Cells(j,"D").Value = Cells(i,"H").Value Then
        Cells(i,"M").Value = "Yes" 'don't need variables for these anymore
        'may want to put an exit to j loop if True
    Else 
        Cells(i,"M").Value = "No"
    End If
    row = row + 1
Loop
```

This compares the values in each of the cells with their respective section (B to J, C to I, and D to H).

Comment: Thank you very much Cyril for helping me again! I have this row highlighted `Set rng = Cells(row, "H")` with a comment "app defined or object defined error"  - can you please advise what I can correct in a code?

Comment: @Irina weird that i just got your comment now, despite you sending 44 min ago and i updated my response 24 min ago.  Please see my update, utilizing the loops for `i` and `j`

Comment: Thank you Cyril! Code stumbles over this `lrj = last(1, Range(Columns("B"), Columns("D")))` saying that ~last~ is not defined here

Comment: @Irina Take a look at the update to lrj... i used `.Find("*", , , , xlByRows, xlPrevious).Row`

Comment: @Irina Glad that worked for you... was looking out for your other post after the issues with formulae not working.  hopefully this fit the bill (ill rated at time of accept).  let me know if there is anything else wrong with this reponse